# simple statistics implementation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, statistics, c++17

**Description**

Mr. Dengklek has you N integers. Among these numbers, determine the largest and smallest numbers.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer N. The next line contains N integers.

**Output Format**

A row contains A B, where A is the largest number and B is the smallest number.

**Input Example**

8

1 -1 1 10 10 6 8 4

**Example Output**

10 -1

Limits

1 ≤ N ≤ 100

-100,000 ≤ (every integer on the second line) ≤ 100,000

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int N,A,B, temp;
  while (true)
  {
    cin >> N;
    if(N > 0 && N <= 100){
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    cin >> temp;
    if(temp >= -100000 && temp <= 100000){
      if(temp < A && temp < B){
        B = temp;
      }
      else if(temp > B && temp > A){
        A = temp;
      }
    }
    else{
      i--;
    }
    
  }
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << B << endl;
  return 0;
  
  
}
```

I got WA and 0pts in this question can you help me figure out what's wrong i've been testing this program and it runs fine

Comment: what is `WA`? How exactly does a program get "points"?

Answer (score 2):

You used the variables `A` and `B` without initializing. Initial values of such uninitiailized local variables are indeterminate. You have to add some code not to use such indeterminate values.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  bool AB_valid = false; // add a flag to indicate if A and B has a valid value
  int N,A,B, temp;
  while (true)
  {
    cin >> N;
    if(N > 0 && N <= 100){
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    cin >> temp;
    if(temp >= -100000 && temp <= 100000){
      if(AB_valid){ // check the flag
        // if A and B contains valid value, use them for calculation
        if(temp < A && temp < B){
          B = temp;
        }
        else if(temp > B && temp > A){
          A = temp;
        }
      }
      else{
        // if they doesn't contain valid value, assign the first value
        A = temp;
        B = temp;
        AB_valid = true;
      }
    }
    else{
      i--;
    }
    
  }
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << B << endl;
  return 0;
  
  
}
```

Comment: @MikeCat, I'd like to have 1 question. The first time you execute the line "if(temp < A && temp < B)", is it true that A and B have not been initialized yet ? If yes, then this will lead to the behavior may be "undetermined" ?

Comment: No. In my code `if(temp < A && temp < B)` will be executed only after some value is assigned to `A` and `B` thanks to the check `if(AB_valid)`.

Answer (score 0):

**MikeCAT's answer is absolutely right**. The OP's problem is caused by the fact that **A** and **B** are not properly initialized, which leads to "undetermined behavior".

Just for fun, I'd like to provide a similar solution that does not require the extra variable "**bool AB_valid**". In this solution, you can simply initialize the value of **A** and **B** directly at the beginning of your function.

I've learned that **each variable must be correctly initialized**, and should also be listed **in one separate line** for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  
  const int MAX = 100000;
  const int MIN = -100000;
  
  int N = 0;
  int A = MIN;
  int B = MAX;
  int temp = 0;
  
  while (true)
  {
    std::cin >> N;

    if(N > 0 && N <= 100){
      break;
    }
  }

std::cout << "\n ***  ";

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    std::cin >> temp;
    if(temp >= MIN && temp <= MAX){
    
        // if A and B contains valid value, use them for calculation
        if( temp < B){
          B = temp;
        }
        
        if( temp > A){
          A = temp;
        }
    }        
    else
    {
      i--;
    }
    
  }

  std::cout << "\n Max = " << A ;
  std::cout << "\n Min = " << B ;

  return 0;  
  
}
```